# search string in unix

Tags: unix, command, find

I want to display all file names conataining the string CHAR * getenv where getenv is a function.

I am using this query

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "CHAR * getenv" {} \;
```

But it is not giving the desired output. It is displaying file names with string CHAR getenv but not CHAR * getenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "CHAR \* getenv" {} \;
```

or

```
grep -rl "CHAR \* getenv" *
```

You need to escape the * as it means 0 or more of the proceeding char (in this case the space)

Answer (score 0):

Use grep -F to prevent the search string being treated as a regex.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -lF "CHAR * getenv" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that bash expansion happens before grep command gets executed: so your line is transformed into `find . -type f -exec grep -l CHAR smt getenv {} \; find . -type f -exec grep -l CHAR smt2 getenv {} \;.`
Replacing double quotes with single quotes should solve the problem because that way bash expansion wont happen.